# Backbone Collection Where function on an attribute which is an object

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I have a collection which contains models which contain an attribute which is an object. I can not work out how to use the collections where function to work on this object.

For example this works fine:

```
myCollection.where({id: 1})
```

But this does not work, it is an invalid property.

```
myCollection.where({myObject.objectValue : "bla"})
```

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 2):

In JavaScript objects (e.g. `{}`), you can only use `String` keys.

Here you'd probably want to write it this way:

```
myCollection.where({ objectValue : "bla" });
```

Note that if the key is a variable, then you could write it this way:

```
var condition = {};
condition[myObject.objectValue] = "bla";
myCollection.where( condition );
```